# Publishing map services in ArcMap gives ERROR 001487: Failed to update published service with server-side data location?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, map-service

I am using the python script provided by arc help to publish map services but keep getting this error. I am using desktop ver 10.3 and publishing to arc server 10.1. Different version isn't a problem. I looked into that already. Here's what I'm getting..

```
Executing: StageService //gis/noble/Region/GulfOfMexico/MAPS/Rusty/PTRL_GOM_GBDS1.sddraft \\gis\noble\Region\GulfOfMexico\MAPS\Rusty\PTRL_GOM_GBDS1.sd
Start Time: Wed Jul 27 12:58:45 2016
Submitted.
Executing...
Start Time: Wed Jul 27 12:58:57 2016
Succeeded at Wed Jul 27 12:58:58 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.33 seconds)
Succeeded.
Succeeded at Wed Jul 27 12:58:58 2016 (Elapsed Time: 13.03 seconds)
Executing: UploadServiceDefinition //gis/noble/Region/GulfOfMexico/MAPS/Rusty/PTRL_GOM_GBDS1.sd "GIS Servers\arcgis on hougsagis01.gs.nblenergy.com_6080 (publisher).ags" # # FROM_SERVICE_DEFINITION # STARTED USE_DEFINITION NO_SHARE_ONLINE PRIVATE NO_SHARE_ORGANIZATION #
Start Time: Wed Jul 27 12:59:10 2016
Submitted.
Executing...
Executing (Publish Service Definition): PublishServiceDefinition i24681d7c-eb34-40ef-8223-32f7fc1c7e34 # {"buildInitialCache":false} #
Start Time: Wed Jul 27 12:59:13 2016
Validating publish options.
Connecting to the server.
Getting basic item metadata for service definition upload.
Getting server information (server folders, data stores, etc.).
Extracting manifiest from uploaded service definition.
Deriving arcgis server service from hosted service (hosted service definition).
Validating service definition.
Determining service's input folder name.
Attempt to find service's input folder.
Creating the service.
ERROR 001487: Failed to update the published service with the server-side data location. Please see the server's log for more details.
ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service.
Failed to execute (Publish Service Definition).
Failed at Wed Jul 27 12:59:14 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.92 seconds)
Failed.
ERROR: the server's publishing job didn't succeed.
Failed to execute (UploadServiceDefinition).
Failed at Wed Jul 27 12:59:13 2016 (Elapsed Time: 3.01 seconds)
```

I cannot access the server folders past  Directory /opt/ags/arcgis/server/usr: permission denied. I cannot access the logs. Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to log into the ArcGIS Server manager -> Site -> Data Store -> Register Folder. Register the folder where your data is contained, publisher path is the location on your box, server path is the location on the server.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR 001487: Failed to update the published service with the
>   server-side data location. Please see the server's log for more
>   details.

It looks like the map data you are trying to publish is in a location where the server cannot access it. Check with your GIS admin to see if you have a data store set up, or if the map data needs to be in a special directory.

If you are the GIS admin, log on to the [Server Manager](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/log-in-to-manager.htm) page and check the logs tab. It will specify the exact data source and location it failed to access.

Answer (score 0):

Just give arcgis account sys admin access in your sql instance.

Steps to give sys admin Access to arcgis account.

1. Go to sql instance.
2. Go to security
3. Go to logins
4. Right click on arcgis user and go to properties
5. Go to server roles
6. check the sysadmin check box

Try publishing now. It worked for me.